# FGLS estimation

Tags: regression, generalized-least-squares

During studying i stumbled over a question asking to give an estimator for beta of the following problem:

$$min (Y-X\beta)´ \Omega (\alpha)(Y-X\beta)$$

if alpha and beta are „independent“, do not vary along each other (i actually don’t know the english term)

I can give the estimator for beta, but it is also asked to show that beta is an FGLS estimator -how would i show that? as long as alpha is unknown any minimizer for beta depending on alpha for the problem is an FGLS estimator - isn’t it? Is there something i am missing?

I am sorry this question is not formulated properly. I don’t have access to a computer at the moment, and I tried finding the correct english terms but was not able to.